# RelativeLayout child does not show up

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I'm working on ActivityOverlay renderer for android. Unfortunately the "progressbar" view does not show up properly.

This is my code so far:

```
internal class ViewImplementation : FormsViewGroup
    {
        private Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay _element;
        private FormsElementWrapper _displayView;
        private RelativeLayout _overlay;
        private ProgressBar _indicator;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            if (!disposing)
                return;

            this._displayView = null;
            this._element = null;
            this._overlay = null;
            this._indicator = null;

            RemoveAllViews();
        }

        public ViewImplementation(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay element, Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _element = element;
            EnsureChildLayers();
        }

        public void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_displayView == null || _overlay == null)
                return;

            switch (args.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.IsBusy):
                    UpdateIsBusy();
                    break;
                case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.Width):
                case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.Height):
                case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.OverlayBackgroundColor):
                    UpdateBackgroundColor();
                    break;
                case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.ActivityColor):
                    UpdateIndicatorColor();
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

            _overlay.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
            //          _indicator.Layout(left-200, top - 200, right - 200, bottom - 200);
//          _indicator.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
            _displayView.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        private void UpdateBackgroundColor()
        {
            _overlay.SetBackgroundColor(_element.OverlayBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
        }

        private void UpdateIsBusy()
        {
            if (_element.IsBusy)
            {
                _overlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                _overlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateIndicatorColor()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                return;

            this._indicator.IndeterminateDrawable.SetColorFilter(this._element.ActivityColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        }

        private void EnsureChildLayers()
        {
            if (_displayView != null)
                return;

            _displayView = new FormsElementWrapper(_element.Content);
            this.AddView(_displayView);
            _indicator = new ProgressBar(this.Context);
            _indicator.Indeterminate = true;
            _indicator.ForceLayout();
            _overlay = new RelativeLayout(this.Context);
            _overlay.SetHorizontalGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            _overlay.SetVerticalGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            _overlay.AddView(_indicator, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent));
            this.AddView(_overlay);

            UpdateBackgroundColor();
            UpdateIndicatorColor();
            UpdateIsBusy();
        }
    }
```

I expected the view to show up centered at minimal size judging by `_overlay.AddView(_indicator, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent));`

However unless i do `_indicator.Layout(left, top, right, bottom);` (with calculated values by myself) i can't get the progress view to display at all. However it appears to me like i am doing something wrong if i'm doing calulations here, because judging by RelativeLayout specifications this should be doable without any calculations.

Is someone able to spot the error here?

Answer (score 0):

This version works. As to why i could not get the other version to work the way i want it to - i am still clueless. At least it works now though. Still curious about the reason still.

```
internal class ViewImplementation : RelativeLayout
{
    private Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay _element;
    private FormsElementWrapper _displayView;
    private RelativeLayout _overlay;
    private ProgressBar _indicator;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (!disposing)
            return;

        this._displayView = null;
        this._element = null;
        this._overlay = null;
        this._indicator = null;

        RemoveAllViews();
    }

    public ViewImplementation(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay element, Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _element = element;
        EnsureChildLayers();
    }

    public void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_displayView == null || _overlay == null)
            return;

        switch (args.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.IsBusy):
                UpdateIsBusy();
                break;
            case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.Width):
            case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.Height):
            case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.OverlayBackgroundColor):
                UpdateBackgroundColor();
                break;
            case nameof(Framework.Controls.ActivityIndicatorOverlay.ActivityColor):
                UpdateIndicatorColor();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateBackgroundColor()
    {
        _overlay.SetBackgroundColor(_element.OverlayBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
    }

    private void UpdateIsBusy()
    {
        if (_element.IsBusy)
        {
            _overlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            _overlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateIndicatorColor()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            return;

        this._indicator.IndeterminateDrawable.SetColorFilter(this._element.ActivityColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
    }

    private void EnsureChildLayers()
    {
        if (_displayView != null)
            return;

        _displayView = new FormsElementWrapper(_element.Content);
        _displayView.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        this.AddView(_displayView);
        _indicator = new ProgressBar(this.Context);
        var layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        layoutParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterInParent);
        _indicator.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        _indicator.Indeterminate = true;
        _overlay = new RelativeLayout(this.Context);
        _overlay.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        _overlay.AddView(_indicator);

        this.AddView(_overlay);

        UpdateBackgroundColor();
        UpdateIndicatorColor();
        UpdateIsBusy();
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Now i derive from RelativeLayout
- Every child has their LayoutParameters set
- OnLayout not customized anymore